# Springboot authentication issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application with spring security configured. I have redirected the login request to `http://localhost:8000` where I'm running my front-end on a python server. Now when I try to post the login to my springboot application, it doesn't work. Even when I try from my postman, it says `405` error. How can I get this working. It works from /login if I put it as html in the same project but not from the python server or postman. What is the difference.

"message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
"path": "/login"

Form Data

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


</head>
<body>


<!-- Add page specific code/html START -->

<div class="container">
    <h1 th:text="#{welcome.message}"></h1>

    <form class="form-signin" name="loginForm" th:action="@{/login}" action="/login" method="POST">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" />

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->


</body>
</html>
```

HTML code hosted on photon server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assessment App</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-default main-header">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class ="pull-left">Assessments</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="login-container col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                            <div class="input-group assessment-input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group assessment-input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="login-form-error-text hidden">Invalid credentials</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../javascript/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="../javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Corresponding js

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#loginform').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();       
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check',
            type : 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify({ j_username :  $('#login-username').val(), j_password : $('#login-password').val() }),
            success : function () {
                window.location.href = '../html/assessment.html';
            },  
            error : function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    });

    $('.form-tab-header').on('click', function () {
        $('.login-form-error-text').addClass('hidden');
        $('.form-tab-header').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.form-horizontal').addClass('hidden');
        $('.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrls;

    @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
    private String ldapBaseDn;

    @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
    private String ldapUserDnPattern;

    @Value("${ldap.enabled}")
    private String ldapEnabled;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assessments/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                //.loginPage("http://htmlcode.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
                .loginPage("http://localhost:8000")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                //.loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();

    }



    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/register");
        // .antMatchers("/assessments/**");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        if(Boolean.parseBoolean(ldapEnabled)) {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
                    .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern)
                    .contextSource()
                    .url(ldapUrls+ldapBaseDn);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new LdapUserDetailsMapper() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
                UserDetails details = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
                return details;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to include csrf values.this is a security precaution mechanism to prevent cross site attacks. your have two options as a workaround :

## 1.Disabling CSRF:

as csrf is enabled by default, both POSTs and PUT Http methods are not allowed with CSRF enabled.
for disabling it you should add this to your security config

```
.csrf().disable()
```

for example you could have such thing:

```
http.
.csrf().disable().
authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
          .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
          .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
```

2.Send csrf token values :

If you are using login page with login form, we need to always include the CSRF token in the login form as a hidden parameter manually in the code:

```
<input
  type="hidden"
  th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
  th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

if you want to login by ajax you should also include these two parameters  included:

first hold the values in some variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrfParameter = '${_csrf.parameterName}';
    var csrfToken = '${_csrf.token}';
</script>
```

then include those into

```
var jsonParams = {};
jsonParams['parentId'] = 1;
jsonParams[csrfParameter] = csrfToken;
// include other values pass ,user, etc.

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: /login,
    data: jsonParams,
    dataType = 'json',
    contentType = 'application/json',

    ...
});
```

---

## More Information

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf
- [Ajax POST results in a 405 (Method Not Allowed) - Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257169/ajax-post-results-in-a-405-method-not-allowed-spring-mvc)
- https://matthewbusche.com/2016/08/06/using-csrf-with-spring-security-and-ajax-calls/
- [Spring Security - 405 Request Method 'POST' Not Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206998/spring-security-405-request-method-post-not-supported/42207397)
- [HTTP 405 Not Allowed - Spring Boot + Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171265/http-405-not-allowed-spring-boot-spring-security)
- [405 Method Not Allowed for POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699724/405-method-not-allowed-for-post)
- [Spring Boot + Security + Thymeleaf and CSRF token not injected automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509392/spring-boot-security-thymeleaf-and-csrf-token-not-injected-automatically)

Comment: I have done the csrf disable already. Should we still include the csrftoken as mentioned in step2?

Comment: could you please include your security config code so i could guide you better?

Comment: Edited my question. Please check

Comment: Please check if cookies are disabled by your browser , if so enable it and recheck

Comment: you mean 405 error gone?  i can not see your successHandler(authenticationsuccessHandler) ? you need somewhere to define if user is authenticated or not

Comment: but issue is that i have login filters so its not even going there.....not able to find where it redirecting from j_spring_security_check. Are there some logs that I look into to debug this more.

Comment: if your 405 error is gone close this question. your should raise another for other issue. you can mention me there i will answer you